# Django NoReverse Match Error

Tags: python, regex, django, web, jinja2

I've been trying to resolve a 'NoReverse Match' for hours.

The error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /myCourses/
Reverse for 'removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'courseID': '15-122'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['myCourses/removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList/(?P<courseID>.....)$']
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/myCourses/
    Django Version: 1.9
    Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
    Exception Value:    
    Reverse for 'removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'courseID': '15-122'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['myCourses/removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList/(?P<courseID>.....)$']
    Exception Location: E:\00 CMU\15112\courseReview\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 508
    Python Executable:  E:\00 CMU\15112\courseReview\myvenv\Scripts\python.exe
    Python Version: 3.4.0
    Python Path:    
    ['E:\\00    CMU\\15112\\courseReview',
     'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python34.zip',
     'D:\\01 SOFTWARES\\Python 3.4\\DLLs',
     'D:\\01 SOFTWARES\\Python 3.4\\lib',
     'D:\\01 SOFTWARES\\Python 3.4',
     'E:\\00    CMU\\15112\\courseReview\\myvenv',
     'E:\\00    CMU\\15112\\courseReview\\myvenv\\lib\\site-packages']
    Server time:    Sat, 12 Dec 2015 21:22:06 -0500
```

It looks like it's able to catch the argument passed to it? But I dunno why it's not able to resolve it.

I have tried each of the following URL pattern:

```
url(r'^myCourses/removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList/(?P<courseID>.....)$', views.removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList, name='removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList'),
url(r'^myCourses/removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList/(?P<courseID>/d+)$', views.removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList, name='removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList'),
url(r'^myCourses/removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList/(?P<courseID>[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9])$', views.removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList, name='removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList'),
```

The relevant HTML+template

```
<h6><big>Courses Enrolled</big></h6>
{% for item in currentList %}
     <p>{{ item }}</p> <a href="{% url 'removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList' courseID=item %}">R</a>
{% endfor %}
```

The relevant view

```
def removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList(request, courseID):
    userProfile = getAssociatedUserProfile(request.user.id)
    userProfile.removeFromUserCurrentlyEnrolled(courseID)
    return redirect('courseDirectory.views.myCourses')
```

Adding the screenshot of the stack-trace just to be sure I am not missing anything

[Stack trace Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60VAG.png)

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

remove all three urlconfs and add this (use `\d+` instead of `/d+`):

```
url(r'^myCourses/removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList/(?P<courseID>\d+)$', views.removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList, name='removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList'),
```

and I am not sure what the `item` is, but it should be an ID `item.id` and not an object:

```
{% for item in currentList %}
 <p>{{ item }}</p> 
 <a href="{% url 'removeFromCurrentlyEnrolledList' courseID=item.id %}">R</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That didn't work...It's able to catch the argument 'courseID' ('15-122' in the screenshot). But the pattern matching fails after trying 1 pattern. That is weird.....Thanks for the help.